# Commutator subgroup having finite index proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to prove: Let G have the presentation $G=<a,b|a^{2}=1,a^{-1}bab=1>$. Prove that G is infinite but the commutator subgroup of G is of finite index in G.

I think I can somehow manipulate the $a^{2}$ and $a^{-1}bab$ terms (or maybe their product?) to derive the commutator subgroup, which would be equal to one which is obviously finite.

But, I am not sure if this is the right track.  And, I'm not sure how to prove G is infinite. It seems it would be because any powers of $a$ or $b$ will never repeat, given then information in the condition - but is that true, and how would I prove it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the relation $ab=ba$ into the original relation, you will get $b^2=1$.
So actually $G/G'=\{G',aG',bG',abG'\}$ which is isomorphic to the Klein four group.
Hence clearly $G'$ has finite index.

Since $G$ is generated by $a,b$, we can say that $G'$ is generated by $aG',bG'$. And since $G/G'$ is Abelian, we add the relation $ab=ba$ into the set of original relation.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2=1$ implies that $a^{-1}bab=abab=1$ we deduce that $aba=b^{-1}$. We deduce that $G$ is defined by the presentation $a^2=1, aba=b^{-1}$.

The dihedral group $D_n$ has the presentation $r^n=1, s^2=1, srs=r^{-1}$. The presentation of $G$ described above implies that there exists a surjective morphism $f:G\rightarrow D_n$ defined by $f(a)=r, f(b)=s$. This implies that $G$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify this group with the group of rigid symmetries of $\mathbb Z$, namely the set of all bijective maps $f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ which satisfy $f(n+1) = f(n) \pm 1$ under composition ; they form a group since if $g,f$ are two such functions, then $f(n-1) = f(n) \mp 1$, hence
$$
(g \circ f)(n+1) = g(f(n+1)) = g(f(n) \pm 1) = g(f(n)) \mp(\pm 1) = (g \circ f)(n) \pm 1. 
$$
Another way to see it is that a map with this property is either a translation (i.e. for some $m \in \mathbb Z$, $f_m(n) \overset{def}= n+m$) or a translation followed by a flip, i.e. $g(n) \overset{def}= -n$ composed with $f_m$ to give $g \circ f_m$ (note that the flips can occur at "half-integers" if you represent the flip geometrically on the real line).

This group is also often called the infinite dihedral group because its presentation is analogous to that of the finite dihedral group, the translations of the integer line playing the role of the rotations on the vertices of the $n$-gon inscribed in the circle.

Clearly this group is infinite and two translations commute with one another, two flips commute with one another and the commutator of a translation and a flip equals
$$
g^{-1} \circ f_{-m} \circ g \circ f_m = f_{2m}. 
$$
(Compute this explicitly!) Since this group $G$ is generated by $g$ and $f_1$ and we just killed $f_2$, the quotient $G/[G,G]$ is generated by $g$ and $\bar f_1$, both of order two and commuting with one another, giving the isomorphism with the Klein group, or $\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z$, or the dihedral group of order four... or whatever you wanna call it!

Hope that helps,